# What is the etymology of the word "snooker"

Tags: etymology

I have heard that the word "snooker" originally meant "beginner" and was coined at the time when the game was first invented.

Is there any truth in this theory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A check [on OED](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=snooker)

> snooker
>
> 1889, the game and the word said to have been invented in
>   India by British officers as a diversion from billiards. The name is
>   perhaps an allusion (with reference to the rawness of play by a fellow
>   officer) to **British slang snooker "newly joined cadet"** (1872).
>   Tradition ascribes the coinage to Col. Sir Neville Chamberlain (not
>   the later prime minister of the same name), at the time subaltern in
>   the Devonshire Regiment in Jubbulpore.

and [word origins](http://www.word-origins.com/definition/snooker.html)

> The most widely canvassed theory of the origins of the term snooker is
>   that it is an adaptation of late 19th-century army slang snooker ‘new
>   cadet’ (‘These embryo generals were called by the somewhat sneering
>   terms of “snookers” or “last-joined”,’ Routledge’s Every Boy’s Annual
>   1872)... The ancestry of snooker (to mean) ‘new cadet’, however, remains a mystery.

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder whether the army cadet meaning was related to  [cocking a snook](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/snook) meaning showing contempt. The Oxford dictionary says that the term _snook_  in this sense is from the late 18th century  but of unknown origin so the timing is consistent. The term could have referred either to the contempt in which old hands would hold cadets or, possibly more likely given many cadets' aristocratic origins, to the arrogance of the cadets themselves.

Answer (score 4):

The online etymology dictionary suggests it derives from a slang term for "newly joined cadet"
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=snooker

So, yes, that would seem to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the other answers, what I find interesting is the hand position involved in "cocking a snook". Taken away from the face and placed on a flat surface, it's not dissimilar to the hand position formed by someone when using the snooker cue.

And given the meaning "to cock" as "to draw or bend back", then an uncocked snook would fit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer, which should be a comment as it is speculation, has a degree of plausibility about it. Snook is first recorded in the OED in 1791.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/416054)