# How did "snookered" become a slang word for "to cheat or to steal"?

Tags: etymology, slang

In this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37185/what-is-the-etymology-of-the-word-snooker) we discussed the etymology of the word "snooker" as a noun, based on a game played on a pool table.  But [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/snookered?s=t) references a form of the word, "snookered" as a slang verb that means to "deceive, cheat, or dupe: to be snookered by a mail order company." (I wonder what the editor had against mail order companies?) Unfortunately, the word's origins are unknown to that site.  Any ideas?

Comment: [The Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=snooker&searchmode=none) says: **snooker** (verb): "to cheat," early 1900s, from snooker (n.), probably because in the game novices can easily be tricked.

Comment: Snooker is played on a snooker table.

Comment: Snooker is (and originally the early forms of pool were) played on a billiards table (billiards pre-dates snooker by quite a way).

Comment: In the movie the Hustler, the name of the pool hall that Eddie (Paul Newman) was hustled by Minnesota Fats (Jackie Gleason) was called Snookies.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary has: **snooker** _v_. to place in an impossible position; to balk, 'stymie' (1889). Nowhere does it suggest that the word in any of its forms ever had any connotation of "cheating".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=snooker&allowed_in_frame=0):

> snooker (verb): "to cheat," early 1900s, from snooker (n.), probably because **in the game novices can easily be tricked**.

That said, the term is also used in the game itself to represent a position of difficulty. Wiktionary alludes to this in [its entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snookered):

> 1. In a situation where the cue ball position is such that one cannot directly hit the required object ball.
> 2. *(informal)* In a difficult situation, especially because of the actions of others.

*Snookers* are not that simple to achieve or to get out of. *To snooker somebody* would be to *place* an opponent in a difficult situation and *to be snookered* would imply that you *are* in a difficult situation. Snookering your opponent is part and parcel of the modern game. But I can see that it could be extended to mean *to trick*. Considering the game's British roots, it might have been considered ungentlemanly to resort to an *intentional* snooker (as the primary aim is to pot the balls), thereby lending the term connotations of deception and cheating.

An American equivalent would be the idiom, [behind the eight ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_pool#.22Behind_the_eight_ball.22).

Comment: I dunno about that; snookering somebody is an integral part of the game of snooker as I see it; it's a perfectly legitimate tactic, and necessary if you don't have enough balls left on the table to beat the opponent.  Extending it to mean *trick* or *deceive* seems a bit of a misuse of the term.

Comment: @Jez  And not just legitimate but the mark of a good player. The primary aim is NOT to pot the balls, it's to get a higher score than your opponent. If you set up a snooker, causing your opponent to miss the target, you gain 4 points as well as control of play.

Answer (score 4):

As a Brit, I have never understood "snookered" to mean "to deceive, cheat, or dupe".

[Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=snooker&title=21st) gives one meaning as "to thwart (a person or a plan)", which is what I've always understood it to mean.

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/snooker) suggests that there are different British & US meanings:

British: leave (someone) in a difficult position; thwart

US: trick, entice, or trap

Comment: Yes. 'Snookered' in Britain means that all avenues have been closed to you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, to "snooker" someone is to maneuver them into an unpleasant situation, perhaps a dead end. That could be a perfectly "legitimate" move, in a game or business dealing.

But it has the connotations of "take advantage of." If you uses that as a starting point, the meaning could be twisted around, at least to "cheating."

Essentially, the difference between "snookering" and cheating is whether you take advantage of someone "fair and square," or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A snooker table has holes that are narrow with curved rails leading into the deep throat.  When the cue ball is in this throat, particularly if against the rail, the cue ball may only be shot pretty much straight out from the hole, and not along either adjacent rail. If your target is thus inacessible, you are “snookered”.

Answer (score 0):

A story I heard was, some locals would talk someone who thought they were good at 8-ball pool into playing it on the Snooker table: with different dimensions and narrower pockets, they would then have an advantage over someone who hadn't played on one.